# undefined reference to `WinMain'

Tags: c++, eclipse, sdl, winmain

I am taking a course in c++ and I've copied the code and done exactly the same as the tutor in the course did in the lecture, however when I do so I get a long error "...undefined reference to `WinMain'" and I don't know what to do.

I am using Eclipse Neon on Windows 10 (and Cygwin, I don't know if it's relevant) and this is my code:

`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
return 0;
```

}
`
The code works and runs without the "#include ", but when I add this line of code the error pops up when I run it (so I guess that's where the problem is). When the tutor in the course run this code it works and prints out the text correctly. 
Can someone please tell me how I get rid of this error and get this simple program to run?

Comment: @Sam I think the question is possibly linked there IIRC. Would you mind to redupe it please.

Answer (score 2):

https://wiki.libsdl.org/FAQWindows#I_get_.22Undefined_reference_to_.27WinMain.4016.27.22

> **I get "Undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'"**
>
> Under Visual C++, you need to link with SDL2main.lib. Under the gcc
>   build environments including Dev-C++, you need to link with the output
>   of "sdl-config --libs", which is usually: -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
>   -mwindows